# What do I set for channel_ids if I only want a trigger to function within bot DMs?

Tags: slack-api

I'm creating a new deno-based modular app and I'm having trouble targeting the message_posted event trigger's channel_ids appropriately.

Similarly, I've considered using `app_mentioned` instead, but the message text will always start with the bot's user ID. Since the filter comparison operators don't include a "contains", I would have to be able to access the bot's user ID in the filter in order to do a strict `==` comparison.

Should triggers like this be created at runtime during app install or a separate "setup" shortcut trigger?

For reference, this is the trigger I'm writing:

```js
const createQuestionTrigger: Trigger<typeof CreateQuestion.definition> = {
  type: 'event',
  name: 'Create Question',
  description: 'Create a new question',
  workflow: '#/workflows/create_question',
  event: {
    event_type: 'slack#/events/message_posted',
    channel_ids: ['???'], // Would like to use something dynamic here
    filter: {
      version: 1,
      root: {
        statement: '{{data.text}} == \'create question\'',
      },
    },
  },
  inputs: {
    interactivity: {
      value: '{{data.interactivity}}',
    },
    user: {
      value: '{{data.user_id}}',
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, using a separate "setup" shortcut trigger is the best way to go since there isn't an event where you can directly subscribe to bot DMs.

One such setup shortcut trigger could be the following:

1. Create a workflow that first sends a message to the user. This will return the channel ID.
2. Use the channel ID to [create a `message_posted` trigger at runtime](https://api.slack.com/future/triggers/event#create-runtime) within the DM between a user and your bot.